# Speed up VBA code when collecting data from a folder of workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

My VBA code is very slow. I think it is activating worksheets when collecting data from all workbooks in a folder, consisting of workbooks of similar data structure.

```
Dim wkbDest As Workbook
Set wkbDest = ThisWorkbook
ChDir strPath
strExtension = Dir("*.xls*")
strPath = 'path_to_folder'
Do While strExtension <> ""
    Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open(strPath & strExtension)
    With wkbSource
        ...
        Set rng = Sheets("Inputs").Range("C9:C14")
        j = 0
        For Each cell In rng
            wkbDest.Sheets("Data_collection").Cells(3 + count + j, 9) = cell
            j = j + 1
        Next cell

        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        .Close SaveChanges:=False

    End With
    strExtension = Dir
Loop
```

Comment: Not sure what you are doing with `3 + count + j` but if you are just moving the entire range from one book to another, you would be better off doing that in go go instead of doing a loop. You also trimmed some code so unless there is a `Select` or `Activate` there isn't anything being selected

Comment: You can turn off screen updating to start (`Application.ScreenUpdating = False`)

Comment: read in an entire range of values into an array with one line of code and process that instead

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things:

1. Turn Application.Screenupdating to false
2. Turn Application.Calculation to xlCalculationManual
3. Minimize the number of operations (copying one cell 1000 times will be slower than copying 1000 cells once)

   In your case you could copy all cells at once like this:

```vb
destWorksheet.Range("C9:C14").Offset(count*5,0).Value2 = srcWorksheet.Range("C9:C14").Value2

'Offset depends on the size of your input (I assume you do a simple copy here)
```

PS: you don't need that Application.CopyCutMode = false line here. You're not using Copy/Paste methods.